# Web сайт без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe, веб-программирование

Ситуация в кратце: имеется веб сайт что то типо яндекс music, плеер перезагружается при переходе с одной страницы сайта на другую
Вопрос: как можно сделать чтоб плеер не перезагружался на сайте, я слышал что через iframe это сделать проще всего, расскажите пжл подробнее про этот способ
сайт делаю с помощью Asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал это с помощью маски, создается 2 `div` в один мы подгружаем сам плеер, а в другой уже сами странички сайта. Получается при переходе на новые ссылки сама страничка не релодится, а с помощью `AJAX` мы просто подгружаем нужные нам странички в `div`.

Comment: да, я так же пытался сделать, но тогда при загрузке страницы, у нас таблицы стилей подключаются нормально,  а вот javascript на странице и его подключение игнорируется браузерами, как быть в данном случае?

Comment: @ИльшатАтышев, игнорируются с сообщением типа "Untrusted origin"?

Comment: ну например я принимаю через ajax частичную страницу которую нужно вставить в див, и в этой частичной странице например прописано где нибудь onclick = 'alert('fdsf')';
и данный скрипт будет игнорироваться...

Comment: @ИльшатАтышев, события лучше отслеживать вне html кода. тогда таких проблем не будет. Попробуйте для этого использовать jQuery. `$(document).on('click','#id', function(){ /* code */ });`